# Text view or UI Label with multiple links

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilabel, uitextview

I have a requirement for iOS application where either using TextView or UILabel, show text which contains text and two links. If someone clicks on text link, that associated link has to open accordingly.

For eg: 
If you see the picture below there are two links. I could achieve this making text view text attributed and modifying text in Attributes Inspector.

Now My question is how to open links when user taps on virginia beach or niagara. How to identify which part of text was clicked by user ?

[image]

Links to be opened:

https://www.vbgov.com/Pages/default.aspx

https://www.niagarafallsusa.com/

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look in [this code](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel) or perhaps even use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [NSMutableAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableattributedstring) to implement this functionality.

I've wrote a method which you can use, call this method from your `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)configureLinks
{
    NSString *fullString = @"Please accept the terms and conditions of virginia beach and Niagara.";
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullString];

    // Adding attributes
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"https://www.vbgov.com/Pages/default.aspx" range:[fullString rangeOfString:@"virginia beach"]];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"https://www.niagarafallsusa.com/" range:[fullString rangeOfString:@"Niagara"]];

    // For underline
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:[fullString rangeOfString:@"virginia beach"]];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:@(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) range:[fullString rangeOfString:@"Niagara"]];

    // Setting attributed string to textview
    yourTextViewOrLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

Comment: It is working but my requirement is to get underline too.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. i have added underline code in @MidhunMP answer.

```
NSString *stringValue = @"Please accept the terms and conditions of virginia beach and Niagara.";
NSMutableAttributedString *output = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringValue];
[output addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"https://www.vbgov.com/Pages/default.aspx" range:[stringValue rangeOfString:@"virginia beach"]];
[output addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:[stringValue rangeOfString:@"virginia beach"]];
[output addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"https://www.niagarafallsusa.com/" range:[stringValue rangeOfString:@"Niagara"]];
[output addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:[stringValue rangeOfString:@"Niagara"]];
yourTextView.attributedText = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use 
[KI Label](https://github.com/Krelborn/KILabel)
simple and easy

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Swift 5

```
func hyperLink(originalText: String, hyperLink: String, hyperLink2: String, urlString: String, urlString2: String) {

let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.alignment = .center

let attributedOriginalText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalText)
let linkRange = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: hyperLink)
let linkRange2 = attributedOriginalText.mutableString.range(of: hyperLink2)
let fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, attributedOriginalText.length)
attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: urlString, range: linkRange)
attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: urlString2, range: linkRange2)
attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: fullRange)
attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.blue, range: fullRange)
attributedOriginalText.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 13), range: fullRange)

self.linkTextAttributes = [
    kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black,
    kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
    ] as [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]

self.attributedText = attributedOriginalText
 }
}
```

Add These

```
var linkUrl = "https://google.com"
var linkUrl2 = "https://facebook.com"
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    if (URL.absoluteString == linkUrl) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL) { (Bool) in

        }
    }
    if (URL.absoluteString == linkUrl2) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL) { (Bool) in

        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Use like this in code

```
textViewMain.hyperLink(originalText: "This App is using Google and Facebook Login", hyperLink: "Google", hyperLink2: "Facebook", urlString: linkUrl, urlString2: linkUrl2)
```